# Pacman: error: duplicated database entry

Tags: arch-linux, pacman

On Arch Linux, I've backed up my system with rsync and restored
it again, but it seems that my way of doing it (which I did get from the Arch
Wiki but must be wrong?) has kept old files deleted
by Pacman.  This results in the error `duplicated database entry`
when I try to upgrade my system with `pacman -Syu`.  What should I do?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suggest that you read the information in the links **[here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=107621)** and **[here](https://mayankjohri.wordpress.com/2014/10/06/tips-arch-linux-how-to-resolve-error-duplicated-database-entry-error-message/)**.

Basically, you need to remove the duplicates (manually or using a script) from `/var/lib/pacman/local/`.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to have worked.  I couldn't get the script to work though, so I had to do it manually.

Comment: This also worked using MSYS/MINGW on Windows. +1

Answer (score 3):

I just went through this. You need to us the `rsync --delete` option. The Arch wiki is wrong about the `--delete` option altering anything in the source system. It will only delete files in destination if they have been deleted or are not in source. This will also prevent a bunch of unwanted files building up if you run the backup on a regular basis.

[Source1](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219949)

[Source2](http://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync)

Comment: Can you explain it better and/or add a link?

Comment: Sure, here you go: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=219949

Comment: And: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Full_system_backup_with_rsync

Comment: It is a suggestion to improve the answer, please add them your answer, and not in the commentary field.

Comment: Be warned: With `rsync –delete`, it *will* delete the Kernel `/lib/modules/<kernel_version>` on destination, so if your kernels aren’t identical, the destination will become *bricked* on the next reboot… Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I tried @Schooled and @maulinglawns answers but both basically bricked my system.

The reason is that `source` was running `linux-5.4.71` and `dest` was running `linux-5.4.72`, released just a day apart.

When `rsync --delete` ran, it deleted all of the kernel modules on `dest/lib/5.4.72/`, which basically led to a bricked system that was incapable of mounting critical file systems, among other things.

After restoring from my `btrfs` snapshot (thank God!!), I figured out the following solution:

```bsh
# From https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/blob/master/arch-pacman-dupe-cleaner
# Copyright © 2020 Theodore R. Smith <theodore@phpexperts.pro>
# GPG: 4BF8 2613 1C34 87AC D28F  2AD8 EB24 A91D D612 5690
# License: Creative Commons Attribution v4.0 International
# @see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/615578/15780

# 0. Login as root.
sudo -s

# 1. Remove the latest dupes from your Pacman DB.
pacman -Syu 2>&1 | grep "duplicated database entry" > /tmp/dupes
for latest in $(for dupe in $(cat /tmp/dupes | awk '{print $5}'); do
    ls /var/lib/pacman/local/$dupe* -d | tail -n1; done); do
    rm -rvf $latest;
done
rm /tmp/dupes

# 2. Remove system of dupe files.
pacman -Syu 2>&1 > /tmp/update-dupes
cat /tmp/update-dupes | grep "exists in file system" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs rm -vf

# 3. Reinstall everything (this will restore anything deleted in #2.).
pacman -Syu
```

Since this is quite a lot, I have added it to my [**BashScripts** repository](https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts) as [`arch-pacman-dupe-cleaner`](https://github.com/hopeseekr/BashScripts/blob/master/arch-pacman-dupe-cleaner).

Answer (score 1):

This command worked for me after changed directory to /var/lib/pacman/local:

```
ls | sort | awk -v re='(.*)-[^-]*-[^-]*$' 'match($0, re, a) { if (!(a[1] in p)){p[a[1]]} else {print} }' | xargs sudo rm -rf
```