# error: duplicated database entry using pacman

Tags: pacman, error-handling

I issue

```
$ pacman -Su
:: Starting full system upgrade...
error: duplicated database entry 'python2-cairo'
 there is nothing to do
```

So I have a look at /var/lib/pacman/local

```
$ ls /var/lib/pacman/local/ | grep cairo
cairo-1.15.12-1
cairomm-1.12.2-2
python2-cairo-1.17.0-1
python2-cairo-1.17.0-2
python-cairo-1.17.0-2
```

How can I:

- See why python2-cairo-1.17.0-1 and python2-cairo-1.17.0-1 are both installed (what packages depend on them)
- Get rid of python2-cairo-1.17.0-1
- Fix the `duplicated database entry` error...

Answer (score 0):

I hadd a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/314702/80291) and tried with:

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/pacman/local/python2-cairo-1.17.0-1/ ~/tmp/
```

Now the error is no longer appearing, but I'm not quite sure if I left anything broken behind

--

I followed @jasonwryan advice, `pacman -Syu` seems to wokr fine, but then I tried with

```
sudo pacman -Qkk | grep mismatch
```

and found several files under `/usr/lib/python2.7/` Modification time mismatch warnings. But apart from that everything seems to be ok

Comment: Run a full update: `-Syu` and then check for issues with `-Qkk`.